# expect module after passing password execute next command without expecting anything

Tags: ansible

trying to understand expect functionality using below piece of code... I know I can do using becom_user, but I would like to check expect module... since there is requirement where I need to use expect module for automating client app CLI

```
  tasks:
    - name: testing expect
      expect:
        command: sudo su
        responses:
          <?i>password<?i>: "password\n"
          <?i>: ls
        timeout: 30
        echo: yes
      register: exp

    - debug: var=exp

fatal: [192.168.153.31]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": "sudo su", "delta": "0:00:30.133859", "end": "2021-09-30 00:51:45.538114", "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 1, "start": "2021-09-30 00:51:15.404255", "stdout": "[sudo] password for XXXXXX: ", "stdout_lines": ["[sudo] password for XXXXX: "]}
```

Comment: @Zoe, may I know the reason why you have deleted my update

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answers, and if you have additional questions, [ask](/questions/ask) a new question

Answer (score 0):

Issue is that `<?i>password<?i>` regex does not match sudo's prompt. [Ansible uses python regex](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/expect_module.html#notes) and angle brackets [have no special meaning](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax) there. If you want case insensetive match use `(?i)password` instead.

Few sidenotes:

- Newline at the end of password string is superfluous. Code works without it.
- `command: sudo su` will hang execution on success as it runs shell. It is more convenient to run something that exits, `command: sudo id` for example.